# Laravel send image from vue to controller

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to save an image when updating an item but I'm having trouble sending the file to the controller in order to save it. This is how I'm sending it

```
submit(item) {
    this.$refs.ruleForm.validate((valid) => {
        if (valid) {
            this.loading = true;
            this.$inertia.post('/courses/' + item.id, {
                name: this.ruleForm.name,
                summary: this.ruleForm.summary,
                description: this.ruleForm.description,
                price: this.ruleForm.price,
                hours: this.ruleForm.hours,
                min_grade: this.ruleForm.min_grade,
                file: this.imagen,
                matery: this.matery,
                remover: this.remover,
                strict: this.strict
            }).then(
                () => {
                    this.$message({
                        type: 'success',
                        message: 'Guardado correctamente.'
                    });
                    this.loading = false
                },
                (res) => {
                    this.$message.error(parseError(res)[0]);
                    this.loading = false;
                })
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
},
```

If I {{imagen}} and {{imageUrl}} in the vue this is the result respectively, this is why I'm sending the imagen and not the url

```
[object File] 

blob:http://dev.inae.com/9c77fa72-b778-45c9-8ab2-0a9084282415
```

When I `Log::info($request)` this is the output, when adding a file and changing text and saving,

```
local.INFO: array (
  'name' => 'Principiante Clase 3 (automático)',
  'summary' => 'Enseñaremos a compresionar el vehículo y la utilización de 
                cambios en vehículo automático',
  'description' => '<p>Enseñaremos a compresionar el vehículo y la utilización de 
                cambios en vehículo automático (viaje a fraijanes).</p>',
  'price' => 52000,
  'hours' => 2,
  'min_grade' => 70,
  'file' => 
  array (
    'uid' => 1576507762527,
  ),
  'matery' => NULL,
  'remover' => false,
  'strict' => false,
)
```

However if I only add the image and don't change anything else, nothing happens in the Log

Code for updating the image in the controller, in the update function

```
//Log is here
$editCourse = Course::find($id);
$destino = "img/courses";
$link = public_path();

if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
    if (!empty($editCourse->image) && file_exists($link . $editCourse->image)) {
        unlink($link . $editCourse->image);
    }
    $image = $request->file('file');
    $imageName = Uuid::generate(4)->string . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $editCourse->image = '/' . $destino . '/' . $imageName;
    $request->file('file')->move($destino, $imageName);
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: when sending files you have to use a form data object over a regular json object, check the documentation here and let me know if you have any questions on how to use it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to use the `FormData` object like so:

```js
let data = new FormData();
data.append('file', this.imagen);
// Attach the other properties.
data.append(...);
$inertia.post(data);
```

This is because you shouldnt upload files using `x-www-form-urlencoded`, instead you should be using `multipart/form-data` which allows you to upload binary data. This also means that the backend will not receive a JSON string anymore, but a form-data response. Laravel should handle this automatically though.

Comment: This is working for me when I change some text and add an image, how could I also fix it where if I only add an image it doesn't save it or even do the log?

Comment: not sure what you mean. Also sounds like a different question

Comment: It's part of the same question, this solution you gave works but only when the name, description or any other thing apart from the image is also changed, but when I only change or add an image then it doesn't get updated

Comment: hard to tell, you could start by simplifying your upload function to `if($image = $request->file('file')){...}`, and then start debugging where it goes wrong.